# how to integrate the 3rd party games for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

My client wants to integrate few games to his iPhone application. For this concern we are ready to buy the paid or we can use the free games as well.

As far as I know the flash isn't supported in iPhone, can you show me a way how should I begin? Is there any way to play flash games on iPhone or are there any games you would like to share with me which can be integrated in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use Flash on a non-jailbroken iPhone.